# Can I request a certificate for *.user1.example.com from Let's Encrypt if I only own example.com domain

Tags: dns, certificate, subdomain, lets-encrypt

If I only own example.com domain, *.user1 is a CNAME of example.com, but I don't have user1.example.com domain, so there can't satisfy DAN-01 challenge on user1.example.com, the challenge only can be satisfied on example.com. Is it possible that I request a cert for *.user1.example.com for such case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you own domain.com you are free to create user1.domain.com subdomain. And then you can make appropriate changes in DNS to satisfy Lets Encrypt requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I am using IBM Cloud Internet Service (like CloudFlare), creating a subdomain is not free, since we will have lots of users, don't want to buy subdomain for each user.

Comment: @MattCui, creation of subdomains is up to you. Support from IBM (DNS) is another story, but you can always create own DNS server ans support the subdomains there

Comment: Do you know if it's free in CloudFlare? Thanks.

Comment: No idea, sorry, probably its better to contact them and to explain your case.  Also you can build own DNS server.